# An Application of Fubini-Tonelli Theorem

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, fubini-tonelli-theorems

In a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1214618/560376), selected answer is started with an application of Fubini's theorem. which I can't figure it out at all. I'm having difficulties with figuring out the differential elements. such as the equation
$$ \int_{0}^{a}\int_0^{f(t)}\mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^{f(a)}\int_{f^{-1}(s)}^a \mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}s $$
and a similar one that's been written for
$ \int_{0}^{f(a)}\int_0^{f^{-1}(t)}\mathrm{d}s\mathrm{d}t $.
Plus I don't understand, how the upper and lower limits have been changed when differential elements
$ \text ds $ and $ \text dt $ are switched.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are referring to is integrating the function identically equal to $1$, it is usually implicitly the case when we are integrating "nothing", maybe it is clearer this way : let $g(s)=1$ $\forall s $ $$  \int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{f(t)}  g(s)\text ds\text dt +\int_{0}^{f(a)} \int_{0}^{f^{-1}(t)} g(s)\text ds\text dt \\$$
$$= \int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{f(t)}  1\text ds\text dt +\int_{0}^{f(a)} \int_{0}^{f^{-1}(t)} 1\text ds\text dt$$

$$=\int_{0}^{a} f(t) dt +\int_{0}^{f(a)} f^{-1}(t)dt$$

where the last equality comes from the fact that $$  \int_{0}^{f(t)}  1\text ds=f(t)$$

Comment: I get that. But my problem is when the $dtds$ changes to $dsdt$ and then suddenly the upper and lower bounds change drastically. My question is, how the upper bounds changed from $ a $ and $ f(t) $ to $f(a)$ and $a$ with lower bound $f^{-1}(s)$ after rewriting $dsdt$ as $dtds$

Comment: This comes from the Fubini Tonelli theorem

Comment: Think about it like this: the initial bounds are $0\leq s\leq f(t)$. We want to change these into bounds for $t$. For the lower bound, we invert $s\leq f(t)$ to get $f^{-1}(s) \leq t$. For the upper bound, we already know that $t$ is constrained to lie between $0$ and $a$, so the upper bound is $t\leq a$. You can also establish these geometrically, by drawing the corresponding region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and taking slices.

Comment: @kieransquared Thanks! and one more thing. why are we allowed to put $f(t)$ and generally functions with _variables_ inside an integral's boundaries? How is one allowed to do that? And if you just summarize what you said in an answer, I'd be glad to upvote and accept the answer!